# Ways to Increase Rails 3 Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

BACKGROUND: I have a list of posts that need to be sorted their 'votes' and then show the top 50 posts.

OBJECTIVE: I am currently using `.take(50)` to accomplish this, as using `.limit(50)` or `.first(50)` show the first 50 posts UNSORTED.

Using `.take` makes the app unusually slow, are there any alternatives to this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine limit and order clauses using something like:

```
Post.all(:order => "votes", :limit => 50)
```

This generates SQL that only selected 50 Posts, but ordered.

Comment: Also, if you don't have it already, you probably want an index on votes. If votes is an association and not a column, you should look into "counter_cache", otherwise my answer probably wouldn't work.

Comment: @fd - Do you need the `.all` method?

Comment: @Beerlington It depends. `.all` returns the real result of the query that is constructed by the prior calls. You could replace it with one of the other methods that do similar tricks (like `.count`, `.first`, `.last`) or leave it off so that you can make further changes to the underlying query (like optionally adding a `.where(..)` or similar) before eventually realising the results.